# Calculating rec range of middle point and radius

Tags: geolocation, geometry, geo

I search a lot for a solution for this thread and surprisingly I didn't find the solution.

I would like to calculate the range(rect) that surrounding my middle point using a given radius.

I'm guessing that the milestones for finding the solution is to calculate the distance between the middle point and the top left point of the rect. From here it's ambiguous for me.

p.s - answers that contains implementation using libraries that run over jvm(java, scala, groovy, python) would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269202/latitude-and-longitude-bounding-box-for-c)

Hope this thread would help someone