# creating boundig box using latitude ,longitude and distance

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have gone through the link
[Given a latitude and longitude, and distance, I want to find a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648917/given-a-latitude-and-longitude-and-distance-i-want-to-find-a-bounding-box?rq=1)
this linke gives the solution to creating bounding box but few things I could not understand .

```
def boundingBox(latitudeInDegrees, longitudeInDegrees, halfSideInKm):
lat = math.radians(latitudeInDegrees)
lon = math.radians(longitudeInDegrees)
halfSide = 1000*halfSideInKm

RADIUS_OF_EARTH  = 6371
# Radius of the parallel at given latitude
pradius = radius*math.cos(lat)

latMin = lat - halfSide/radius
latMax = lat + halfSide/radius
lonMin = lon - halfSide/pradius
lonMax = lon + halfSide/pradius
rad2deg = math.degrees
return (rad2deg(latMin), rad2deg(lonMin), rad2deg(latMax), rad2deg(lonMax))
```

in the above code what is the value of radius  and what is represent by 6371 in `RADIUS_OF_EARTH` ?

Any one can explain ?

Thanks

Comment: why did you set C# and Sql-server tag? the code is not in C#.

Answer (score 0):

according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) 6371km is the mean radius of the earth. I can't see a definition of `radius` in the piece of code you show, but it should be set to `RADIUS_OF_EARTH`, because `pradius` is the horizontal projection of the radius (according to the comment).