# Java - New Point, X Distance from Latitude / Longitude point

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, trigonometry, haversine

I need to take a point, and determine what the point is that's N miles north-west of it, and N miles south-east of it. It'll essentially create a bounding box around the initial point.

I've looked around a bit, and found some stuff about Haversine, but it seems like all of the code implementations are for the distance between two points, not a new point component from a point.

Is there an existing implementation of such a thing, preferably in Java, that already exists? Or any other language?

Here is the methods I'd imagine that'd I'd need:

```
public float longitudeFromPoint( float lat, float long, int vertical, int horizontal )
{
    // something
}

public float latitudeFromPoint( float lat, float long, int vertical, int horizontal )
{
    // something
}

float startLat  = 41.829347;
float startLong = -87.633788

float northWestLat  = latitudeFromPoint( startLat, startLong, 1, -1 );
float northWestLong = latitudeFromPoint( startLat, startLong, 1, -1 );

float southWestLat  = latitudeFromPoint( startLat, startLong, -1, 1 );
float southWestLong = latitudeFromPoint( startLat, startLong, -1, 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be worth reading: [Finding Points Within a Distance of a Latitude/Longitude Using Bounding Coordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates). It gives a short theoretical background on spherical coordinates and provides some java code.

The link is borrowed from the accepted answer to this thread on SO: 
[Calculating bounding box a certain distance away from a lat/long coordinate in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689096/calculating-bounding-box-a-certain-distance-away-from-a-lat-long-coordinate-in-j?rq=1)