# Define a bounding box by radius in Elasticsearch

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, geospatial, bounding-box

I am in the process of migrating an app from Solr to Elasticsearch.

This app provides reverse geolocalisation : Returns the N nearest points for a given set of coordinates.

In Solr, this is largely optimized by [using a bounding_box](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#bbox_-_Bounding-box_filter) before sorting the results foudn inside that box (from 1-2 seconds to 50ms), [this discussion on github](https://github.com/komoot/photon/issues/19#issuecomment-42484741) explains it deeper.

I want to achieve the same in ES because simple geo_distance filter also gives me slow results in ES.

When Solr ask me for a central point and a radius (eg. 5Km), [ES needs the coordinates of the bounding_box](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-filter.html).

It is way more complex to compute those values than just give a radius and let some robust tool compute the bounding_box it self.

I am wondering if the calculation of bouding_box is made by Solr or by Lucene.
In the later case I could expect ES to provide access to this feature, but I can't find any thing in official documentation or by googling.

I would like to avoid the overhead of implementing [complex maths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689096/calculating-bounding-box-a-certain-distance-away-from-a-lat-long-coordinate-in-j) in my app if I can leverage Elasticsearch or Lucene codebase. Moreover it would probably be done faster in Java than in my nodejs app.

I would take any advices, before making a feature request on ES and start reinveting the wheel.

Comment: Have you considered [geo_distance_range](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-geo-distance-range-filter.html) filter?

Comment: Or [geo_distance](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) (even better) filter?

Comment: Yes, I already have this implemented, but its slow. I thus thought it was for the same reason than Solr was slow via the geodit() function (Edited my question to precise that this is a performance issue and to link to explanation of the optimisation).

Comment: With `geo_distance`, ES uses a bounding box calculation to exclude as many documents as it can and it only runs the geo-distance calculations for those matches that fall within the box. As a slight improvement, you could try to set the `distance_type` property for `geo_distance` to "plane" which is a faster calculation formula than the default `sloppy_arc` one. But, of course, it's also less accurate.