# How to convert bounding box coordinates to radius?

Tags: java, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am given a bounding box, latitude and longitude, which are the following:
`Bounding box = 59.3518076,59.5915769,24.55017,24.9262831
Latitude = 59.4372155
Longitude = 24.7453688`

My question is, how do i convert bounding box into radius using those 3 parameters?

Comment: There is already a question like this: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689096/calculating-bounding-box-a-certain-distance-away-from-a-lat-long-coordinate-in-j)

Comment: Sadly, they're asking for bounding box in that question. I do have one but i have no idea how to convert it back into radius :)

Comment: If you read the whole thing, you will see that he is also trying to get a radius. I would scroll down and read the top two answers.

Comment: i did but still i have no idea how to convert my bounding box into radius

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the algorithm in my opinion:

- first find the shortest side of the bbox: min(|lat1-lat2|,|lon1-lon2|)
- convert its length in decimal degrees to kilometres (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Precision)
- you have the minimum radius

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. I also found a way to use entire bounding box in my code but i will keep the original idea in mind

Comment: I implemented the algorithm (which gives both dimensions of the bounding box, so needs only to check only for the minimum. I used the haversine function https://github.com/sabas/sabas.github.io/blob/master/tools/bboxcalculator.html#L123