# Specifying a radius with long. and lat.

Tags: dictionary, gis

I have a data set with longitude and latitude data for metro stops in NYC. For example one XY coordinate looks like this

```
40.799419°N 73.968158°W
```

I would like to create a radius around these points so I could identify people within a specific distance to a metro stop. I was wondering whether it is possible to do this by using fewer digits to specify a location. For example can I convert the last three digits (or so) in the XY coordinates  to zeros to identify a bigger region.

```
40.799000°N 73.968000°W
```

Please note that I do not want to use a gis software to do this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; by converting those digits to 0 you have simply moved your metro stop to a different location.

A simplistic approximation would be to use a [minimum bounding box/rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689096/calculating-bounding-box-a-certain-distance-away-from-a-lat-long-coordinate-in-j) - add/subtract some [finite small increment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) to both the latitude and longitude values, e.g., .001 to get a bounding box like

```
            ---------------------40.800419°N . 73.969158°W
            |                                |
            |     40.799419°N . 73.968158°W  |
            |                                |
40.798419°N . 73.967158°W --------------------
```

with your coordinate at the center. If you want an actual circular distance you are going to have to get into GIS-type thinking and some libraries to help you do the coordinate calculations.