# Bing API for finding nearby cities

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps, reverse-geocoding

Is there a Bing API for finding nearby cities given a city name or lat/long combination?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Bing provides this, but you build your own from the data available from [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/)

They provide an API to get places near a given lat/lng: http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo

Or you can also go all out and implement a solution for your own needs using their data, as per this answer: [Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the city/country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country/6355183#6355183)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm familiar with the geonames webservices.  The findNearby from geonames was actually what prompted me to see if Bing had a similar option.  We are using Bing in our application and don't want to have to rely on the free geonames service (which I've noticed has  uptime issues) and we didn't want to pay for another service on top of Bing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: [Bing Maps API Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701729.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this API still only provides geocode data for individual locations.  It doesn't provide a list of 'nearby' cities.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is no  Bing API for finding nearby cities.

That said, it would be possible to 'cook your own' using the existing APIs. However, one thing that would need clarification is what 'nearby' means. I presume you mean within a specific radius of a given point (determined by a city name or lat/long combination).

Using the Bing Api it would be fairly trivial to implement an algorithm to reverse geocode a location and then test for places within x distance.

Failing that, you could use something like geoPlugin, it is free and you can put it on your sever - thus avoiding 3rd party up-time issues.
http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php#php_class

Take a look at the nearby places features, this does exactly what you want.
http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/extras

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. However, it's relatively simple to get the bounding box for a given coordinate and then use the Bing Maps API with that.  I'm doing this and used this solution to get what I needed...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314146/73680