# Find points within a distance using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation, geospatial

I have question about spacial sql query using MySql;
I have a table with latitude and longitude colums;
I would to get all points nearest by my geoPosition using my distance (radius).
I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    id, (
      6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

- Is this query a good way about the performances?
- How can I change this query if I would consider an square that contains the points? is preferable to use a square?

Comment: Its good enough for me [see](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) 3K mysql database

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple map projection and straight distances for example equirectangular projection. In the formula on this website you can also use a simplier formula without the square root:http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. Of course you can use a bounding box to filter the query:[How to calculate the bounding box for a given lat/lng location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location), https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-given-a-distance-and-latitude-longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak on the subject of performance in MySQL but when working on the same problem in SQL Server I build a box based on my `distance` than I can limit results quickly in `WHERE` clause by simply verifying for `Lat` and `Long` to be within boundaries. At that point it becomes simple arithmetic comparison. After I have narrowed down number of results at that time I check the `Distance` from my original point.

The whole point of building a box first is to reduce number of records that are involved in complex mathematical calculation.

Here is my example from SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @Lat DECIMAL(20, 13) = 35.7862
   ,@Long DECIMAL(20, 13) = -80.3095
   ,@Radius DECIMAL(7, 2) = 5
   ,@Distance DECIMAL(10, 2)
   ,@Earth_Radius INT = 6371000;

SET @Distance = @Radius * 1609.344;

DECLARE @NorthLat DECIMAL(20, 13) = @Lat + DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius)
   ,@SouthLat DECIMAL(20, 13) = @Lat - DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius)
   ,@EastLong DECIMAL(20, 13) = @Long + DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius / COS(RADIANS(@Lat)))
   ,@WestLong DECIMAL(20, 13) = @Long - DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius / COS(RADIANS(@Lat)));

SELECT *
    FROM CustomerPosition AS cp
    WHERE (
            cp.Lat >= @SouthLat
            AND cp.Lat <= @NorthLat )
        AND (
              cp.Long >= @WestLong
              AND cp.Long <= @EastLong )
```

Results of original select I store it into temp table and than evaluate it to see which ones actually `Within` specified distance.