# How can I collect all the longitude and latitude within a bounding box?

Tags: api, instagram, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

im using Instagram API to collect images from certain areas , using longititude and latitiude.

Iam now trying to find a way to create something such as a bounding box to actually collect all images within that box.

Is it possible that someone can post a  pseudo code , or any suggestion of how i can accomplish this , it would help if someone can post a simple code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gramfeed to search photos on a map by setting a radius around a latitude,longitude:

http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

This can be accomplished by using instagram media search API:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the links , thats exactly what i want to do , however do you know a way i can accomplish this in terms of coding?

Comment: Also are you suggesting that the latitude and longtitude are the components to create the bounding box?

Comment: Instagram will return media within a circular area, you may have to manually calculate a bounding box within that circular area and filter out lat,lng outside the bounding box

Comment: Do you know any turtorial of how to calculate a bounding box?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location