# What algorithm is necessary to calculate lat/lon radius around a point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, location

Lets say we are given the lat/lon coordinates `(51.2993, 9.491)`

and now I want to know what is the range of lat/lon coordinates in a 50km box/circle centered around this point.

(e.g. `51.2993 +/- 0.005, 9.491 +/- 0/003`)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's basically infinity, unless you tell us what are the restrictions and limits of the coordinate system plus more information about the units and numbers.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location